# Riak Search - Results limited to first 10000

Tags: riak, riak-search

I have a Riak Search node running and am trying out some test queries to get a feel for performance.

I'm running a query via the search shell, and the results are being restricted to the first 10000. I want all results to come back, but can't find where this 10000 limit is coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the riak_search root directory, edit rel/riaksearch/etc/app.config and in the riak search configuration, set your max_search_results:

```
...

{riak_search, [
                {search_backend, merge_index_backend},
                {java_home, "/usr"},
                {max_search_results, <put your max>}
               ]},
```